# Does the new trend of "no transaction fee" accounts substantively change the academic study of mathematical finance?

Tags: research

It seems like it would. If so, what are some examples?

Comment: TBH I have not seen it mentioned in the research that I read.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it? Customers are still paying spread and execution slippage - another type of less obvious transaction cost much the same as regular fees, which are magnified by adverse selection associated with trading larger size.

Execution either at midprice, VWAP or TWAP is almost impossible unless you are trading with gigantic short-term alpha.